# How to handle hiding dynamic elements in JQUERY with different names but same CSS class

Tags: java, jquery, css, spring

On my jsp page I have a loop that loops elements in a collection, which create dynamic fields.  Each iteration creates a field type called editType and names it as editType1, editType2...

There are 3 possible options for editType.  Based on what the user choosese for editType, I need to hide the irrelevant fields and only show the fields that pertain to the editType that they have chosen.  For each editType option there is a cooresponding tbody named editTypeA, editTypeB and editTypeC.  An example is if editType = A then tbody name EditTypeA should show and EditType B and EditTypeC should be hidden.  Since the tbody for each edity type will be created each time in the loop, how can I have the jquery function display the appropriate tbody for just the clicked editType field and not for all the editType fields on the page.

The jsp page looks like:

```
 <c:forEach items="${surveyInfo.allSurveyEdits}" var="surveyEdits" varStatus="status">                              

            <tr class="altrow" align="left">
                <td height="19">Type:</td>
                <td width="17%" colspan="3">
                    <sf:select path="allSurveyEdits[${status.index}].editType" id="editType${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey">
                        <sf:option value="" label="Select" />
                        <sf:option value="A" label="A" />
                        <sf:option value="B" label="B" />
                        <sf:option value="C" label="C" />               
                    </sf:select>                      
                </td>                   
            </tr>   

     <tbody id="editTypeA">

            <tr align="left">                      
                 <td>Edit Description:</td>
                 <td colspan="3">
                    <sf:select path="allSurveyEdits[${status.index}].editFormatDesc" id="editFormatDesc${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey">
                        <sf:option value="" label="Select" />
                        <sf:option value="Data is entered in correct format" label="Data is entered in correct format" />
                        <sf:option value="Correct decimal precision is entered" label="Correct decimal precision is entered" /> 
                    </sf:select>
                 </td>
            </tr>


     </tbody>

     <tbody id="editTypeB">

            <tr align="left">
                <td>Edit Description:</td>
                <td colspan="3">                        
                     <sf:select path="allSurveyEdits[${status.index}].editRangeDesc" id="editRangeDesc${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey">
                        <sf:option value="" label="Select" />
                        <sf:option value="PCT Diff" label="PCT Diff" />
                        <sf:option value="Defined Range" label="Defined Range" />   
                    </sf:select> 
                </td>
             </tr> 


  </tbody>

  <tbody id="editTypeC">

            <tr align="left">
                <td>Edit Description:</td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <sf:select path="allSurveyEdits[${status.index}].editIntegrityDesc" id="editIntegrityDesc${status.count}" cssClass="inputbox-survey">
                        <sf:option value="" label="Select" />
                        <sf:option value="Required Field Validation" label="Required Field Validation" />
                        <sf:option value="Data Type Validation" label="Data Type Validation" /> 
                        <sf:option value="Calculation Validation" label="Calculation Validation" /> 
                    </sf:select>
                </td>
             </tr>

 </tbody>

 </c:forEach>
```

The jquery function that I have come up with but works only if the page doesn't have multiple items in the collection:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { 

         $("#editTypeA").hide(); 
         $("#editTypeB").hide(); 
         $("#editTypeC").hide(); 


         if($("#editType").find("option:selected").val() == "A") { 
                  $("#editTypeA").toggle(); 
              } 

         if($("#editType").find("option:selected").val() == "B") { 
                  $("#editTypeB").toggle(); 
              } 

         if($("#editType").find("option:selected").val() == "C") { 
                  $("#editTypeC").toggle(); 
              } 

         $("#editType").change(function() { 

              if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "") { 
                  $("#editTypeA").hide(); 
                  $("#editTypeB").hide(); 
                  $("#editTypeC").hide(); 

              }

              if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "A") { 
                  $("#editTypeA").toggle(); 
                  $("#editTypeB").hide(); 
                  $("#editTypeC").hide();   


                  $("#editTypeB").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 

                     $("#editTypeC").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 

                } 

              if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "B") { 
                  $("#editTypeB").toggle(); 
                  $("#editTypeA").hide(); 
                  $("#editTypeC").hide(); 

                   $("#editTypeA").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 

                     $("#editTypeC").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 

              } 
              if($(this).find("option:selected").val() == "C") { 
                  $("#editTypeC").toggle(); 
                  $("#editTypeA").hide(); 
                  $("#editTypeB").hide(); 


                   $("#editTypeA").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 

                     $("#editTypeB").find(':input').each(function() { 
                    switch(this.type) { 
                        case 'select-multiple': 
                        case 'select-one': 
                        case 'text': 
                        case 'textarea': 
                            $(this).val(''); 
                            break; 
                        case 'checkbox': 
                        case 'radio': 
                            this.checked = false; 
                    } 
                    }); 
              }                               
           }); 





        });
```

Comment: The problem is on the client - show your CLIENT CODE, not your source code.

Comment: not sure what you mean I am have my jsp code posted, what client code are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by making the tbody name to contain the name of the editType element, this enabled me to use *= selector to get elements that contained the name.

Thanks for all the help.

```
 $('select[name*="editType"]').each(function (i) { 


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your code, you need to do this (although it's a bit of a hack about):

```
    $(".altrow").each(function() {
        $parent = $(this).parent();
        $editA = $parent.find("#editTypeA");
        $editB = $parent.find("#editTypeB");
        $editC = $parent.find("#editTypeC");

        $allElements = $editA.add($editB).add($editC);

        $editType = $parent.find("#editType"); 

        $parent.find($allElements).each(function() {
           $(this).hide(); 
        });

        if($editType.find("option:selected").val() == "A") { 
           $editA.toggle();
        } 
    });
```

You should be able to go from here with those variables...

**Edit** However, you'll still need a unique table per loop which will be your classed as your unique parent element.

Comment: not sure if I understand...there are multiple EditTypeA for each editType.  I need to know which editType changed and show/hide that particular tbody

Answer (score 0):

You are creating multiple `<tbody>` elements with the same `ID`. The `ID` attribute is meant to only be attached to one element on the page. Look at the generated source. It seems to me that your `<tbody>` elements should be created outside the loop, but I don't really know what your data is.

If I were doing something like this, I would probably create entirely separate `<table>`s for each edittype, and use the `ID` attribute on the tables to show/hide them.

Comment: i modified the code so that each iteration of the loop creates a new table but I still can't understand how to hide the relevant EditTypeA, EditTypeB, and EditTypeC based on the selected editType.